# Azure B2C: Default Display Name

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Our Sys Admins want to be able to search for users and identify them by their Given Name and Surname, both of which we are collecting/requiring when they sign up.

We are NOT allowing users to specify a "Display Name" value when they create an account.

The management portal uses the "Display Name" as one of the three columns displayed in the "Users" pane.

It would be useful for Systems Administrators to be able to see the values given for Surname and Given Name in the user management portal to be able to identify the correct account.

I do know that there is a filter/search that I can type keywords into, and it does in fact find accounts with first or last names matching those, but if their name does not show in the "User Name" (which has been set to be the email), it is difficult to be sure of a match.

I could write code to update the display name using the graph API when we receive a connection from a new account, but I'd rather not.

Is it possible to configure the Display Name to use the "Given Name" + "Surname" values when viewing the list of users that have created B2C accounts?

Or perhaps, is it possible to show other attributes as columns as well as or instead of "Display Name"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Display Name in Azure B2C custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723095/update-display-name-in-azure-b2c-custom-policy)

Comment: Maybe? I stopped working with B2C about 6 years ago.

Comment: Sorry for the automatically created unintentional question - the comment should be read as  [“Possible duplicate”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339563/the-auto-comment-does-this-answer-your-question-generated-when-voting-to-clos)

Comment: Well mine's older, so it's the other one that's a duplicate so nya :P (jk). Seriously though, the other one seems like a great post and answer. I just can't speak to whether it works or not.

Answer (score 3):

I use Azure B2C custom policy for signup process and had the same requirement - DisplayName = FirstName + LastName. I use claims transformation to achieve that.

```
<ClaimsTransformations>
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" TransformationMethod="FormatStringMultipleClaims">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" TransformationClaimType="claim1" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" TransformationClaimType="claim2" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0} {1}" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
</ClaimsTransformations>
```

Comment: I'm a little out of touch with recent changes to Azure AD B2C. Could you provide a link to the documentation on ClaimsTransformations with a very brief description of what they are and how to use them?

Comment: Hi @Pytry, I found the solution as part of [Azure AD B2C Custom Policies starter pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-policies-understanding-contents#claim-transformations)

Comment: The particular example given above can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#formatstringmultipleclaims

Answer (score 1):

I fix that with a Web Job and Graph API. If that is an option for you I'm happy to share the code.

Comment: I would love taking a look at any examples you have. I am using Java and Spring. We are going to (not started yet) create a Java Client that mirrors the operations of the Graph API, since there are a few other things we need to do anyways (like deleting inactive accounts). Still, it would be nice if IT had more configuration options so we would not have to create our own custom support tools.

Comment: find the C# Console App which I run in an Azure Web Job [here](https://gist.github.com/KaiWalter/69ec5ee7db22f55f5049e1fb83280ef1)