# Update Display Name in Azure B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are trying to update the Display Name in a custom Azure B2C policy using a Claims Transformation, but we can't get it to work. The policy executes with no errors, but the display name does not get updated.

We DO NOT want the user to input the display name.

There's a similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668121/azure-b2c-default-display-name), but the transformation offered in the solution does not pass validation when uploading it to Azure.

Here's the updated transformation we are using:

```
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" TransformationMethod="FormatStringMultipleClaims">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0} {1}" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

There is a sample that uses the above transformation [https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%206.md#specifying-the-claims-transformation (link currently broken)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%206.md#specifying-the-claims-transformation).

Comment: How are you invoking this claims transformation? i.e. From which technical profile? As an input or output claims transformation?

Answer (score 13):

The transformation you have posted is correct. So I assume that your not using it in a correct order.

You have written, that you do not want your users to set up a display name. Therefore, you only have to inluce the transformation within the technical profile that actually writes the user's details into the Active Directory.

Example giving:

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>

      <!-- Transform optional claims (given name, surname) to proper display name -->
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>

      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>

      <PersistedClaims>
        <!-- Required claims -->
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="unknown" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration" />

        <!-- Optional claims. -->
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
      </PersistedClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Now the transformation takes the optional name claims and create a proper display name before (input transformation) the values are written into the directory.  If neither a given name nor a surname is set, the fallback value (unknown) will be used. Any read operation on the dictionary (Login etc.) will return the one-time transformed display name.

However, you can adjust your technical profile for collecting this information (e.g. LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail) to require a value for those fields.

```
 ...
 <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
 <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" Required="true" />
```

Comment: you lost me on that final bit, say what?
"However, you can adjust your technical profile for collecting this information (e.g. LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail) to require a value for those fields." ?
But I got it working thanks :-)