# Azure AD B2C Custom Policies and remove display name from sign up UI

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've been playing around with AD B2C custom policies using the Starter Pack and I'm trying to work out how to NOT collect the *Display Name* on the sign up page, but record it by concatenating the captured *GivenName* and *Surname*.

I've worked out how to do the concatenation (via `ClaimsTransformations`), but I can't work out how hide the *Display Name* field on the sign up page so it's not collected.  The only examples I've been able to find are disabling email verification and collecting additional data ... not collecting less data and hiding the fields in the UI.

Comment: Hi @Dazfl, I am not writing an answer, Can you share how to disable the email verification?

Comment: Hi @RoshanMaddumage ... the documentation can explain how to do it better than I can (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-disable-email-verification)

Comment: REF: claim transformation used to build display name - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#formatstringmultipleclaims

Comment: how to do the concatenation (via ClaimsTransformations) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723095/update-display-name-in-azure-b2c-custom-policy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />` in the `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail` technical profile.

Comment: Perfect! That worked! Is there any documentation that explains this? I can't find any in the microsoft docs ... but I could be having a man's look (as my wife would say). :-)

Comment: There isn’t, it’s more based on the concept that to add a field, you add an output claim, therefore the reverse is implied. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-configure-user-input

Comment: Is this in the SignUp policy? this on it's own doesn't work for me

Comment: I've removed every instance of <OutputClaim ClaimRefereenceId="displayName"/> from my code and it still shows up