# Generate Display Name with Azure function and API connector Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using the azure b2c sign-up policy(built-in policy) in my application. I am getting the first name and last name from the user during sign-up. Since I am not taking display name, so display name is getting saved as unknown.

I am thinking of creating an azure function that will update the display name as firstname_lastname and link it to user flow as an API connector. Can you please let me know if you have tried the same. It will be great if I can get a sample azure function code for the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Display Name in Azure B2C custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723095/update-display-name-in-azure-b2c-custom-policy)

Comment: I want to do that using built-in policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this in a custom policy.

However, for the API connector, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector?pivots=b2c-user-flow#continuation-response-1:%7E:text=Overrides%20any%20value%20that) say that the claim returned "overrides any value that has already been provided by a user in the attribute collection page". You haven't provided "displayName" so this may not be possible.

There are some function quick starts [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connector-samples#azure-function-quickstarts).

In your case, the claims names in the API are:

"displayName" = "givenName" + " " + "surname"