Azure AD B2C Custom Policy - Using OutputClaimsTransformation
I would like to transform the displayName from two Outputclaims, surName and givenName. I used the example provided here to FormatStringMultipleClaims.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" TransformationMethod="FormatStringMultipleClaims">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0} {1}" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>

After trying a few things from the above resource, I still see 'unknown' as the display name for the test User I signed up with.
Here is how my TechnicalProfile looks with User Sign Up:
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignUp</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="CustomLocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="zipCode" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="phoneNumber" />
            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
          </OutputClaims>

          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>

          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-CustomUserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-CustomUserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="mail" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration" />

            <!-- Optional claims. -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="zipCode" PartnerClaimType="postalCode" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="phoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="mobile" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

I asked for the givenName and the surName during sign up, and they are returned as an OutputClaim. After the User has provided the givenName and the surName, I make a request to the ClaimsTransformation to transform givenName and surName into a displayName. Finally, I persisted DisplayName.
Unfortunately, displayName still comes out as 'Unknown'

Looks like the solution is to remove the OutputClaimsTransformations from CustomLocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail as that did nothing and add an InputClaimsTransformations in CustomUserWriteUsingLogonEmail.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723095/update-display-name-in-azure-b2c-custom-policy

Try setting displayName as an output claim in "CustomLocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail".

Do you mean like this? It looks like it is already set:

